# How can I get weechat to signal gnome-terminal on a highlight?

Tags: terminal, irc, bell

When using a terminal based client like weechat, weechat does not signal the terminal letting the user know that they have been highlighted.   How can this be done?  I would like my terminal to blink when I am highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure about WeeChat, but it's possible in mIRC and Irssi using [my patch](http://mikelward.com/software/gnome/flashing-terminal).

If you can get WeeChat to make an audible bell when you are mentioned/highlighted, then my patch will work for WeeChat too.

Comment: Is there a good reason why the GNOME people haven't included this?  I found your patch from 2008.

Comment: @penguin359: The way I see it: the Gnome Terminal maintainer doesn't want to add it because he thinks it won't be used by many people.  Read the Gnome bug and make up your own mind.

Answer (score 2):

Never used weechat, but basically, you want it to send out a audible bell, also known as ^G or \007.  Some programs like bash/readline can be configured to do a visual flash instead of a audible bell.  With a visual flash, Gnome Terminal won't know there was an update.

Comment: I will have to try it, thank you.  I will let you know.

Comment: You will also need [a patch](http://mikelward.com/software/gnome/flashing-terminal).  [git repo](https://github.com/mikelward/gnome-terminal).

Comment: @Mikel shoot!  I can't believe after all this time, Gnome Terminal hasn't had it working.  I never tested it, but I assumed it would work like other terminal.